# Angular JS Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] simple code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! 
You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
```

I've searching a lot about my problem and can not find solution and I bet it's something silly.

My code:

### myangular.js

```
 (function(){

    var app = angular.module('newapp', []);

    app.controller("controller", function(){
        this.creador = "daniel";
    });

});
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="newapp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/myangular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="controller as cont">
        <strong>Hello World {{ cont.creador }}</strong>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's suspect that the console message you've logged out says `myApp`, not `newapp`. Wrong file/project/folder?

Comment: Pass a $scope to your controller function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use an anonymous jQuery function wrapper. Just use your code and it will work fine.

```
var app = angular.module('newapp', []);

app.controller("controller", function(){
     this.creador = "daniel";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code, and I think the error message should be `newApp` not `myApp`.

You are using an `IIFE(Immediately-Invoked Function Expression)` but you are just defining IIFE not calling it. You are defining your `newApp` in this IIFE.

```
(function(){

    var app = angular.module('newapp', []);

    app.controller("controller", function(){
        this.creador = "daniel";
    });

})();
```

OR don't use IIFE say like bellow

```
var app = angular.module('newapp', []);

app.controller("controller", function(){
    this.creador = "daniel";
});
```